# Does facebook embedded video have tracking?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-insights, embedded-video

On facebook you can see who watced your videos, and make retargeting, dark post etc. This is because the user is logged into facebook, and facebook tracks it. 
But what if [I embed the facebook video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player) on a blog eg., does the tracking continues, or do I need to implementen a facebook tracking pixel on the blog aswell before the tracking on the video can continue, and retargeting is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... yes, facebook does track when using embedded videos.
Read [link 1](http://www.crispvideo.com/blog/using-videos-effectively-facebook/) & [link 2](http://www.outbrain.com/blog/infographic-how-video-views-count-across-platforms)